# How to print longitude and latitude coordinates in Java ME?

Tags: java-me

> print longitude and latitude coordinates in java me but getting errors
>   TRACE: 
>   Could not open and read file: C:\Users\Amit
>   Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000003.iijava.io.IOException:
>   storage_open(): No such file or directory, C:\Users\Amit
>   Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000003.ii
>
> - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=0
> - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=21
> - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=26
> - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=8
> - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
> - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=7
> - .unknown..(), bci=68
> - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=58
> - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=6
> - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=30
> - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=10
> - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=3
> - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=419
> - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=122
> - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=60
> - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=194
> - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=2
> - .unknown..run(), bci=5
> - java/lang/Thread.run(), bci=5

My code is:

```
Criteria cr = new Criteria();
@Override
public void startApp() {
    int i=5;

    double[] locat = null;
    cr.setHorizontalAccuracy(500);

    LocationProvider lp = null;
    try {
        lp = LocationProvider.getInstance(cr);
    } catch (LocationException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Mygpspro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ex);
    }
    try {
       locat=getLocation(lp);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

       Logger.getLogger(Mygpspro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    }
   System.out.println(locat[0]); 
   System.out.println(locat[1]); 
}
public static double[] getLocation(LocationProvider lp) throws Exception

{

double []arr = new double[3];

if(lp != null)
{

    switch(lp.getState())
    {
        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            Location l = lp.getLocation(-1);
            QualifiedCoordinates  c = l.getQualifiedCoordinates();
            if(c != null )
            {
              double lat = c.getLatitude();
              double lon = c.getLongitude();
              double alt = c.getAltitude();
              String latStr = Double.toString(lat).substring(0,7);
              String lonStr = Double.toString(lon).substring(0,7);
              lat = Double.parseDouble(latStr);
              lon = Double.parseDouble(lonStr);
              arr[0] = lat;
              arr[1] = lon;
              arr[2] = alt;

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Co ordinate is null!!");
            }
            break;

        /* Other cases are handled here */

        default:
            break;
    }
}

return arr;

}
```

Comment: From the stack trace the issue seems to be related with file manipulation (and not location). Please, replace Logger calls with simple System.out.

Comment: I have replace all logger calls with System.out and still getting same errors.

Comment: please help me to  get the coordinates.

Comment: sir please make a rply I don't know what is happening please tell what is wrong in my code...

Comment: Maybe there is nothing wrong with your code, but your app does not have the permission to request location. Does your app has proper MIDlet-Permission settings?

Comment: sir how to configure proper MIDlet-Permission settings?

Comment: What tools are you using to develop?

Comment: sir Im using net beans and javame-sdk 8.2

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/nbmp40-security-136005.html